# Ray Dataset: ArrowInvalid: Unrecognized filesystem type in URI: gs://

Tags: pyarrow, ray

I've recently began exploring Ray and am having trouble just reading data from my GCS bucket.

Here is the code:

```
ray.data.read_parquet("gs://path")
```

Here is the error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Unrecognized filesystem type in URI: gs://
```

In the same environment/notebook, I was able to read data from the same directory using `pd.read_parquet`

Answer (score 4):

Pyarrow (as of 6.0.1, the latest at the moment) does not have support for a direct GCS filesystem and is not able to recognize `gs://` URIs.  You can create a GCS filesystem using an [fsspec adapter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#using-fsspec-compatible-filesystems-with-arrow).  I think you can use this in Ray with:

```
import gcsfs
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')

ray.data.read_parquet("path", filesystem=fs)
```

Pyarrow 7.0.0 (which will likely release in the next month) should include some support for a native GCS filesystem (I'm not entirely clear on how much will be included in 7.0.0 but I know it is actively being worked on so check the release notes).  [Support for `gs://` URIs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14893) does not yet appear to have been implemented.